# How to retrieve the row that caused exception using spring framework's namedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am inserting user information where a few columns have unique constraint on them one of which is email id. In testing when I try to insert the same user twice I get the

`org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException`

it also does tell me which column violated the unique constraint but it does not give me back the row that triggered the violation. I have seen solution where the user has caught such exception and run a query based on column on which violation was triggered but does spring have anything that will return the row details along with the exception.

I tried looking but there is so much information explaining why the exception happened that I do not find a solution that returns the row that caused the violation.

Comment: I don't think so. The "best" solution if this is going to be a common occurrence is to insert each row one by one (not ideal) and catch the `DuplicateKeyException` and feed back to which entry caused the issue. This would mean however if the process is error prone that you can carry on with the process and deal with the erroneous entries separately.